# How to dismiss UIImageView when view is pressed in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *myLayout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
    myLayout.scrollDirection=UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:myLayout animated:YES];

    UIImageView *recipeImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 100, 250, 250)];
    recipeImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    recipeImageView.layer.borderWidth = 8.0;
    [self.view addSubview:recipeImageView];
    NSString *selectedRecipeImageFileName = [self.getName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *selectedRecipeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:selectedRecipeImageFileName];
    recipeImageView.image = selectedRecipeImage;
}
```

I'm using a collection view. First, I press on any image, then it will show a `UIImageView` on the view. If I press on another image, then again that image will appear. At this point it works properly. After that, I want to have it so if I press on a blank space then the image view hides. Please give me some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your tap gesture:

```
[recipeImageView removeFromSuperview];
```

But your image view must be accessible to any function. So you can just make a function and then call it whenever you want.

**UPDATE**

Sorry for delayed response. Try this:

in your .h file:

first in @interface... add `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>`

and after @interface:

```
@property UIImageView *recipeImageView;
```

in your .m files `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIGestureRecognizer *taps = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(removeImageView)];
    taps.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    taps.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:taps];
```

and somewhere in your .m file:

```
-(void)removeImageView
{
    [_recipeImageView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: After using UIGestureRecognizerDelegate which delegate method will do  call

Answer (score 0):

Keep a pointer to that UIImageView and call `removeFromSuperview` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tap gesture on your main view to remove the UIImageView from superView.

```
//inside viewDidLoad initilise tap gesture
    tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(removeImageView:)];
     tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *myLayout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
myLayout.scrollDirection=UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:myLayout animated:YES];

UIImageView *recipeImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 100, 250, 250)];
recipeImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
recipeImageView.layer.borderWidth = 8.0;

// tap gesture was initialised globally.
 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

[self.view addSubview:recipeImageView];

NSString *selectedRecipeImageFileName = [self.getName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIImage *selectedRecipeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:selectedRecipeImageFileName];
recipeImageView.image = selectedRecipeImage;
```

}

Now inside the removeImageView:

```
- (void)removeImageView:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
     UIView *view = sender.view; 
     //Now here check the views on which user is taping and match if user is taping on desired view where you want remove the images from superView. and also remove the tap gesture from view.

}
```

Comment: No we can't this bcoz button will hide all the objects, so after that scrolling will also stop.

Comment: Then the best way is use the tap gesture. and then recognize the tapped view in your gesture function. If user is tapping the desired view that you want then dismiss the visible image views. I will update my answer in few minutes with another code.

Comment: What is in tapGesture. tapGesture is nil when we add it to view.

Comment: Inside view did load you can initialise it. It need to be global otherwise every time a new tap gesture object will be added to your view.